# aggrid mouseup event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

Need to add mouseup event for each aggrid cell which works in react virtualization scenarios and sorting filtering scenarios,

```
let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".ag-cell");

    elementsArray.forEach((elem) => {
        elem.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUpHandler);         
    });
```

Comment: I think it's not a good way with `react`. could you show me `.jsx` code?

Comment: Can't you do something like this?
<AgGridReact onCellMouseOut = {this.onCellMouseExit} />

Comment: I need mouseup event not mouseout.

Comment: cellMouseOut  will call when you  leaves a cell.
cellMouseOver => Mouse enters,
cellMouseOut => leaves cell,
cellMouseDown => mouse down.

Can you try it and let me know the result?

Comment: I need mouseup event